# How can I update a disease prediction model with new treatment group data while maintaining the original causal relationships?

Tags: machine-learning, causality, difference-in-difference, epidemiology, counterfactuals

**Context:**

- I have a prediction model which predicts the probability of getting a disease.
- This prediction model has been created based on data of patients who did not get any form of treatment.
- I use this model on new patients. Patients which have a probability of higher than X of getting the disease will be treated. Patients with a lower probabilty than X will not be treated. The treatment lowers the probability with Y.

**Question:**

I want to update my prediction model with the data of the new patients. What is the best way to do that?

---

**The problem**

You can not simply add the new patients data to the original data and then retrain the model because it will change "the causality" of the model. Since the treatment will interfer with the rest of the variables of the prediction model. I hope the example below will clarify this statement:

**Example:**

Originally we created a logistic regression model to predict getting lungcancer (yes/no) we used the variables, age, family history of lungcancer(yes/no), gender, currently smoking(yes/no), smokinghistory(yes/no).

We used this model on a new patients. There is a new patient who is a smoker and has a probability of higher than X getting lungcancer and you give him treatment ("lungcancer chance reduction pills") and the patient ends up not getting lungcancer. Now we would like to use the data of this patient to update the original model.

However if we add the data of this patient (smoker) to the original model with as outcome 'not getting lungcancer' the model will be biased with the idea smoking --> **not** getting longcancer. Which is incorrect.

What is the best way to add new patient data to the model while keeping any 'causal' relationships?

**EDIT: To show that updating prediction models with 'treated' patients is a more theoretical methodological problem I shall add an example which I encountered in a business setting:**

Originally we created a logistic regression model to predict whether a custumor would stop his mobile phone subscription (yes/no) we used the variables, age, number of send texts, number of calls, years having a subscription, internet usage.

We used this model on a new customers. There is a new customer with a decreasing internet usage (sign of stopping the subscription) and has a probability of higher than X of stopping the subscription. You 'treat' this customer ("call him/her and offer discount") and the customer ends up not stopping the subscription. Now we would like to use the data of this customer to update the original model.

However if we add the data of this customer (low internet usage) to the original model with as outcome 'not stopping his subscription' the model will be biased with the idea low internet usage--> **not** stopping his subscription. Which is incorrect.

Comment: *"Since the treatment will interfer with the rest of the variables of the prediction model"* Your current model is not based on people that received some treatment?

Comment: Yes indeed. I shall update the question to prevent confusion.

Comment: On what is your current prediction model based instead? *(without knowing on what your current model is based, how can anybody say how the inclusion of data from patients with a treatment is gonna do something?)*

Comment: I don't think the exact details of the model are relevant for the question. I am looking for a methodological way of dealing with the issue. I think all treatments (assuming there is a treatment effect) will change the nature of the data and therefore of the model. Please take a look at the example provided for a more practical point of view.

Comment: It is relevant for the question to be more concise. If it is not clear what sort of prediction model you are using, what sort of data is presently used to create that model, or even what you consider/define as 'model' (this is not explained in your example) then is becomes very hard to answer this question. What is 'the original data' and why do you believe that you can not add this new patients to it? This interference is not clear to me (or at least not why you can turn that interference into a general question without explaining details).

Comment: I updated the example part of the question. Thanks for helping me out. Feel free to ask if you need more clarification.

Comment: I was under the impression that 'treatment' was something like a medicine, but now I have the idea that it is not like that. You do not speak about a model that predicts the effect of a medicine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105115/discussion-between-koot6133-and-sextus-empiricus).

Answer (score 1):

> However if we add the data of this patient (smoker) to the original model with as outcome 'not getting lung cancer' the model will be biased with the idea smoking --> not getting lung cancer. Which is incorrect.

I would add a `had_treatment` boolean in your input variables. That way, the model should understand that "having had treatment" is a major predictor for not developing cancer.

Although the above suggestion is just a way to mitigate the problem that you mention, without suppressing it entirely. If you want to do things really properly, you should refrain from updating your model with new patients, whether you decided to give them treatment or not (if you update the model with patients whom you decided to to give treatment only, this will bias the data in favour of people who have an a-priori lower probability of getting cancer, and you probably don't want that).

So, in a nutshell, one of two ways:

- either include a boolean had_treatment (yes/no) in your input data
- or refrain from adding new patients (including the ones you decided not to give treatment)

One last consideration: when adding new patients data, it's highly likely that this data is biased towards people being at risk. Why would a non-smoking 22 years old with no family antecedent come see you to have a check? Should you decide to include new patients data, you need to counter that bias one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am hoping that there will be a third option. There must some option since updating of models will happen all the time in lots of different settings. I shall add an example from marketing to show the generability of the problem.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful.